# delphi improve GUITESTRUNNER code

Tags: delphi

I observed a buggy behaviour of the Delphi GUI test runner class. While working with 2 displays on my computer (Laptop) the DUNIT user interface is shown on any of my 2 screens. As long as there are 2 displays connected i can operate the GUI testrunner. Once I disconnect the second display from my laptop the GUI testrunner form is created / shown on the secpond screen and I can't operate this form.

Is there any way to force the dunit GUI testrunner to display the form inside the visible viewport. I was thinking on a helper class, but I do not have any concrete solution Idea ....

Comment: The position is saved in the Dunit.ini file in the test project's folder (in the left, top, width, and height values in the GuiTestRunnerConfig section). If you don't want the configuration saved, uncheck the AutoSave Options item in the Options menu. (It's not "buggy"; it's doing exactly what it is supposed to do, according to the source.)

Comment: You have the source code for DUnit. You can change the code to force the window to be located within the screen boundaries.

Comment: @KenWhite Except it is probably a bug for a form to show itself offscreen. No idea why this is a SO question though - personally I'd either file a bug report or (even better) fix it and then submit a patch...